# Invalid hook call error, but everything seems to be good

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-web

Hello guys that's the first time I'm asking a question right here, but i'm really running out of ideas on this ...

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
>   the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
>   following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

For a React-native project running on React-native web, I want to run an init function in my component with the `useEffect()` hook. In order to get data from a local library that i've imported with `yarn link` (**that library doesn't use react**).

As you can se bellow my hook is in a functional component :

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import Premium from './Premium';

const Widget = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  const init = async () => {
    console.log('working');
  };

  return (
    <Premium />
  );
};

export default Widget;
```

I've also check my versions of react and react-dom as it says [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) and I only got one copy of react / react-dom and react-native.

To be sure, i've checked this in two different ways as it says in the official documentation.
( Via `npm ls react-native` and also via `console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);` )

Here's my **package.json** :

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint .",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.6",
    "@poool/eslint-config": "0.0.1-alpha.3",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.0.1",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.2",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "14.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "4.0.1",
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "1.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.12.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks for all ! And feel free to tell me if I did something wrong, that's the first time for me :)

Comment: try {widget} instead of {Widget} classname

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Hi Robin, the full error message is indicate at the top of my post and you got also a clue in the title :) 

Ps: I've tried to change the name of the component but it changes nothing

Comment: the code block you've posted looks good. You will have to show more code.

Comment: @LonelyCpp I agree that it looks good ahah that's the only part of code where the problem is, I just render this component and without the hook it's perfectly working :'(
What could I add to help you ?

Comment: perhaps init is using some hook unintentionally?

Comment: @LonelyCpp what do you mean ? Init is just there to console.log something random. ( I even could remove it and still have this issue ). Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally find an answer on my own, and I wasn't giving enough details about my problem.

The fact is that I had 2 `node_modules` :

- one for my components (I'm working on a library).
- one for an example app made for running my components via react-native for web.

To solve my issue I simply follow https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991#issuecomment-435587809 ( That i saw 10000 times), in order to point on the same React copy. And it worked perfectly !

Thanks for your comments !

Comment: hi facing the same issue, may i know where did u place the code snippet?

Comment: Hi, I placed it in the webpack config of my react web example app.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that this error also appears when you run `react` and `react-dom` twice in the browser. For example if it's bundled with the main application, but also bundled inside a plugin coming from npm.

In short running the `react` code twice in the browser will not work and can also lead to this confusing error.